# удаление нескольких записей по checkbox PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

извините пожалуйста за детский вопрос, необходимо сделать удаление записей по checkbox, что то не получается. где ошибка? Подскажите пожалуйста

$search_date_array = get_event($action, $time_recv);

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($search_date_array); $i++) {
        echo '<hr/>';
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><td><strong>Время</strong></td><td>' . $search_date_array[$i]->time_recv . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td> </td><td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" ' . ($search_date_array[$i]->time_recv  == "1" ? ' checked="checked"' : "") . ' /></td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/>';

    }
    if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    {

        for ($i=0;$i<$search_date_array;$i++)
        {
            $time_recv = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
            $sql = "DELETE  FROM event_logs_month WHERE time_recv ='$time_recv'";
            $result = mysqli_query($page->mysqli_handle, $sql);
        }
    }
```

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что в POST->checkbox у тебя приходит не массив с элементами, а стройка. Что бы отправить массив на сервер, следует указать name=checkbox[1], где 1 - ключ в вложенном массиве. Сделай var_dump($_POST) и проверь данные, которые приходят на сервер.